# how do i change this to be able to generate a random item from my list?

Tags: java, random, arraylist

[my list containing fruits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D4AR.png)

i'd like for the code to pick (At random) a fruit from my list and then display it.

the code works currently but doesn't have the random function i'd like for it to have.
This is a school project so any help is appreciated

Comment: Please, [post your code as well formatted text, not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: just do `Collections.shuffle(list)` once.  Then iterate thru the list.  No need to keep shuffling.  Note that doing it this way will not repeat previous shown elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain random integer number and then use it as an index to get from list.

Try this sample:

```
int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(0, list.size());
System.out.println(list.get(randomIndex));
```

instead of your "for" cycle

Some explanation for newcomer:
***nextInt*** method will return some random integer number from 0 (index cannot be less then 0) to ***list.size()*** number exclusively (counting starts with 0, so if you have 3 elements, the third element will be at index 2) to prevent IndexOutOfBoundException.